# Best .net Method to create an XML Doc

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to figure out what the best method is for writing an XML Document. Below is a simple example of what I am trying to create off of data I am pulling from our ERP system.  I have read about XMLWriter, but thought I would see if there are any other better methods.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Orders>
  <Order OrderNumber="12345">
    <ItemNumber>0123993587</ItemNumber>
    <QTY>10</QTY>
    <WareHouse>PA019</WareHouse>
  </Order>
  <Order OrderNumber="12346">
    <ItemNumber>0123993587</ItemNumber>
    <QTY>9</QTY>
    <WareHouse>PA019</WareHouse>
  </Order>
  <Order OrderNumber="12347">
    <ItemNumber>0123993587</ItemNumber>
    <QTY>8</QTY>
    <WareHouse>PA019</WareHouse>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

Comment: It is in the source. I tried to edit the post to HTML encode the XML and it didn't work either. To be honest even though I use this site nearly every day I am not sure how to post XML!

Comment: Do your item numbers really need to be zero padded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to build XML in C# code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Josh's answer shows how easy it is to create a single element in LINQ to XML... it doesn't show how it's also hugely easy to create multiple elements. Suppose you have a `List<Order>` called `orders`... you can create the whole document like this:

```
var xml = new XElement("Orders",
    orders.Select(order =>
        new XElement("Order",
            new XAttribute("OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber),
            new XElement("ItemNumber", order.ItemNumber),
            new XElement("QTY", order.Quantity),
            new XElement("Warehouse", order.Warehouse)
        )
    )
);
```

LINQ to XML makes constructing XML incredibly easy. It also has support for XML namespaces which is pretty easy too. For instance, if you wanted your elements to be in a particular namespace, you'd just need:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://your/namespace/here";
var xml = new XElement(ns + "Orders",
    orders.Select(order =>
        new XElement(ns + "Order",
... (rest of code as before)
```

LINQ to XML is the best XML API I've worked with... it's great for querying too.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I am using .Net 3.5 so this should work perfectly.  As you can see I am still new/ignorant when it comes to XML so I am trying to get a better understanding of the basics and what methods will be best suited. I appreciate all of the suggestions and will definitely try them out.  Thanks!

Comment: That is exactly what I would have too...I would build an Order Object from our DB and want to then use that to build the XML.  Should work perfectly.

Comment: Small error in first example, there shouldn't be a semicolon in second-last line. To small a fix to make an edit to above post, so here's a comment. Also, I'd put each end-parenthesis on each own line, indended correctly :-)

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest using the classes in [System.Xml.Linq.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) which contain an XML DOM API that allows for easy build-up of XML structures due to the way the contructors are designed. Trying to create an XML structure using the System.Xml classes is very painful because you have to create them detached then separately add them into the document.

[Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387021.aspx) of XLinq vs. System.Xml to create a DOM from scratch. Your eyes will bleed when you see the System.Xml example.

Here's a quick example of how you would use XLinq to build up part of your doc.

```
var xml = new XElement("Orders",
    new XElement("Order",
        new XAttribute("OrderNumber", 12345),
        new XElement("ItemNumber", "01234567"),
        new XElement("QTY", 10),
        new XElement("Warehouse", "PA019")
    )
);
```

**TIP** Although it's a little unorthodox (though no worse than some of the language butchering that has become popular lately), I have on occasion used C#'s type aliasing feature to minimize the code even further:

```
using XE = System.Xml.Linq.XElement;
using XA = System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute;
...
var xml = new XE("Orders",
    new XE("Order",
        new XA("OrderNumber", 12345),
        new XA("ItemNumber", "01234567"),
        new XA("QTY", 10),
        new XA("Warehouse", "PA019")
    )
);
```

Comment: As long as the target is .NET 3.5 or 4.0, that's a very good suggestion.

Comment: If the item number really needs to be zero padded, you'd have to specify it as a string rather than as a number. I'm hoping that this isn't the case though.

Comment: The ItemNumber is actually a UPC so they are generally zero padded.  Internally everyone refers to it as ItemNumber because that is the field in our ERP system and it is populated with the UPC. I will try out your suggestion thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8):

What about this : create a class "Order" and one "Orders", and then serialize those out to XML - seems a lot easier to me than creating the XML bit by bit from hand....

Since you say you're pulling the data off your ERP, you probably already have objects and classes for "Order" and so on - maybe it's sufficient to put a few [XmlElement] attributes on your classes and you're good to go!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlLinqTest
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "")]
    public class Orders
    {
        private List<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement("Order")]
        public List<Order> OrderList
        {
            get { return _orders; }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [Serializable]
    public class Order
    {
        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement]
        public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public int QTY { get; set; }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement]
        public string WareHouse { get; set; }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and in your main app something like this:

```
Orders orders = new Orders();

Order work = new Order() { ItemNumber = "0123993587", OrderNumber = "12345", QTY = 10, WareHouse = "PA019" };
orders.OrderList.Add(work);

work = new Order() { ItemNumber = "0123993587", OrderNumber = "12346", QTY = 9, WareHouse = "PA019" };
orders.OrderList.Add(work);

work = new Order() { ItemNumber = "0123993587", OrderNumber = "12347", QTY = 8, WareHouse = "PA019" };
orders.OrderList.Add(work);

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orders));

using(StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"D:\testoutput.xml", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    ser.Serialize(wr, orders);
}
```

Working with objects and then serializing them out to disk seems a lot easier to me than fiddling around with XDocument and other APIs.

Answer (score 3):

If your use case is simple, nothing could possibly simpler and easier to use than XmlTextWriter.  That said, one alternative would be to use an XmlDocument object to create and append all of your nodes.  But I think it's easier to write and maintain code that uses XmlTextWriter if you're creating a document from scratch rather than manipulating one.  Using XmlTextWriter should be very straightforward:

```
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output);
        writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\"");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Orders");
        //...start loop...
        writer.WriteStartElement("Order");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("OrderNumber", "12345");
        writer.WriteElementString("ItemNumber", "0123993587");
        writer.WriteElementString("QTY", "10");
        writer.WriteElementString("WareHouse", "PA019");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        //...loop...
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Close();
```

Comment: I would say that LINQ to XML is significantly simpler than XmlTextWriter.

Comment: Note that there aren't any constructors taking a TextWriter and an encoding... you'd need to give a filename or a Stream... or *just* give a TextWriter, but use one which published an encoding of UTF-8.

Comment: -1: you need a `using` block around the `StringWriter`, and `XmlTextWriter` is deprecated in favor of `XmlWriter.Create`

Comment: Jon - you're right, my mistake.  John - not technically deprecated, but a good recommendation.  I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new language called [XCST](http://maxtoroq.github.io/XCST/) that compiles to C#.

```
<c:template name='c:initial-template' expand-text='yes'>
   <c:param name='orders' as='IEnumerable&lt;Order>'/>

   <Orders>
      <c:for-each name='order' in='orders'>
         <Order OrderNumber='{order.Number}'>
            <ItemNumber>{order.ItemNumber}</ItemNumber>
            <QTY>{order.Quantity}</QTY>
            <WareHouse>{order.WareHouse}</WareHouse>
         </Order>
      </c:for-each>
   </Orders>
</c:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create following XML document having some part of it parametrized.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wap-provisioningdoc>
  <characteristic type="BOOTSTRAP">
    <parm name="NAME" value="SYNCSETTINGS" />
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic type="APPLICATION">
    <parm name="APPID" value="w5" />
    <parm name="TO-NAPID" value="INTERNET" />
    <parm name="NAME" value="SYNCSETTINGS" />
    <parm name="ADDR" value="http://syncserver/sync" />
    <characteristic type="RESOURCE">
      <parm name="URI" value="pb" />
      <parm name="NAME" value="Contacts DB" />
      <parm name="AACCEPT" value="text/x-vcard" />
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="RESOURCE">
      <parm name="URI" value="cal" />
      <parm name="NAME" value="Calendar DB" />
      <parm name="AACCEPT" value="text/x-vcalendar" />
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="RESOURCE">
      <parm name="URI" value="notes" />
      <parm name="NAME" value="Notes DB" />
      <parm name="AACCEPT" value="text/plain" />
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="APPAUTH">
      <parm name="AAUTHNAME" value="username" />
      <parm name="AAUTHSECRET" value="password" />
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

And here's my code that does this with single LINQ statement.

**Make a note that creating XML document above using LINQ and saving it to XML file preserves the XML document formatting and keeps line-breaks and carriage-returns that makes the document properly tabified.**

```
public string CreateOTAXmlFile(string Username, string Password)
    {
        var ota = new XDocument(
                    new XElement("wap-provisioningdoc",
                        new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "BOOTSTRAP"),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "SYNCSETTINGS"))
                                    ),
                        new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "APPLICATION"),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "APPID"), new XAttribute("value", "w5")),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "TO-NAPID"), new XAttribute("value", "INTERNET")),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "SYNCSETTINGS")),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "ADDR"), new XAttribute("value", "http://syncserver/sync")),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "RESOURCE"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "URI"), new XAttribute("value", "pb")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "Contacts DB")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AACCEPT"), new XAttribute("value", "text/x-vcard"))
                                        ),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "RESOURCE"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "URI"), new XAttribute("value", "cal")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "Calendar DB")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AACCEPT"), new XAttribute("value", "text/x-vcalendar"))
                                        ),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "RESOURCE"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "URI"), new XAttribute("value", "notes")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "Notes DB")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AACCEPT"), new XAttribute("value", "text/plain"))
                                        ),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "APPAUTH"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AAUTHNAME"), new XAttribute("value", Username)),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AAUTHSECRET"), new XAttribute("value", Password))
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            );

        ota.Save(Server.MapPath("~/OTA/") + Username + ".xml");
        return (ota.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the xml document containe
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();// Create the XML Declaration, and append it to XML document
XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
doc.AppendChild(dec);// Create the root element
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Library");
doc.AppendChild(root);
// Create Books
// Note that to set the text inside the element,
// you use .InnerText instead of .Value (which will throw an exception).
// You use SetAttribute to set attribute
XmlElement book = doc.CreateElement("Book");
book.SetAttribute("BookType", "Hardcover");
XmlElement title = doc.CreateElement("Title");
title.InnerText = "Door Number Three";
XmlElement author = doc.CreateElement("Author");
author.InnerText = "O'Leary, Patrick";
book.AppendChild(title);
book.AppendChild(author);
root.AppendChild(book);
book = doc.CreateElement("Book");
book.SetAttribute("BookType", "Paperback");
title = doc.CreateElement("Title");
title.InnerText = "Lord of Light";
author = doc.CreateElement("Author");
author.InnerText = "Zelanzy, Roger";
book.AppendChild(title);
book.AppendChild(author);
root.AppendChild(book);
string xmlOutput = doc.OuterXml;
The same code but using an XMLWriter to a memory stream.

XmlWriterSettings wSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
wSettings.Indent = true;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, wSettings);// Write Declaration
xw.WriteStartDocument();
// Write the root node
xw.WriteStartElement("Library");
// Write the books and the book elements
xw.WriteStartElement("Book");
xw.WriteStartAttribute("BookType");
xw.WriteString("Hardback");
xw.WriteEndAttribute();
xw.WriteStartElement("Title");
xw.WriteString("Door Number Three");
xw.WriteEndElement();
xw.WriteStartElement("Author");
xw.WriteString("O'Leary, Patrick");
xw.WriteEndElement();
xw.WriteEndElement();
// Write another book
xw.WriteStartElement("Book");
xw.WriteStartAttribute("BookType");
xw.WriteString("Paperback");
xw.WriteEndAttribute();
xw.WriteStartElement("Title");
xw.WriteString("Lord of Light");
xw.WriteEndElement();
xw.WriteStartElement("Author");
xw.WriteString("Zelanzy, Roger");
xw.WriteEndElement();
xw.WriteEndElement();
// Close the document
xw.WriteEndDocument();
// Flush the write
xw.Flush();
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[ms.Length];
buffer = ms.ToArray();
string xmlOutput = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the non-LINQ solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want (or can't) to use `LINQ to XML`, neither to duplicate your `Order` class to include XML serialization, and thinks `XmlWriter` is too much verbose, you can go with plain classical `XmlDocument` class:

```
// consider Order class that data structure you receive from your ERP system
List<Order> orders = YourERP.GetOrders();
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("Orders"));
foreach (Order order in orders)
{
    XmlElement item = xml.CreateElement("Order");
    item.SetAttribute("OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber);
    item.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("ItemNumber")).Value = order.ItemNumber;
    item.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("QTY"       )).Value = order.Quantity;
    item.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("WareHouse" )).Value = order.WareHouse;
    xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good suggestions in this thread, but one that hasn't been mentioned:  Defining an ADO `DataSet` and serializing/deserializing using the `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` methods.  This can be a very simple and attractive solution.  Your XML isn't in quite the right format, but it's close.

Answer (score 0):

I found it largely depends how complex your original data is.

If your data is nicely organized in objects and it is sufficient to dump it in XML, Linq is very verbose and powerful. But as soon as there are object inter-dependencies, I don't think you want to go with the Linq one-liner, as this is real pain to debug and/or extend.

For those cases, I'd prefer to go with XmlDocument, create a help method to facilitate adding attributes to an element (see below), and use Linq in foreach loops around the XML creation blocks.

```
private void XAttr(ref XmlNode xn, string nodeName, string nodeValue)
{
    XmlAttribute result = xn.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute(nodeName); 
    result.InnerText = nodeValue;
    xn.Attributes.Append(result);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You just right click on your code window , select InsertSnippet
 follow this Link

```
 Data-Xml.....>Xml>Xmlcreate
```

its very easy