# what's the best method to generate xml file

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to build XML in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-code)

what's the best method to generate xml file?

Comment: this question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `XmlWriter` class in .Net

```
        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        writerSettings.Indent = true;

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("d:\\MyFirstXmlFile.xml", writerSettings);

        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("People");

        writer.WriteStartElement("Person");
        writer.WriteElementString("Name", "Zain Shaikh");
        writer.WriteElementString("JobDescription", "Software Engineer");
        writer.WriteElementString("Facebook", "http://www.facebook.com/zainshaikh");
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        writer.Flush();
```