# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2007

when i am trying to open a page in sharepoint the above error is appearing. actually i used the following code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.Write(GenerateTagCloud());
    Response.End();       
}

private string GenerateTagCloud()
{
    SPWeb myweb = null;
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        SPSite mysite1 = new SPSite(mysite.ID);
        myweb = mysite1.OpenWeb();
    });

    myweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    SPList categories = myweb.Lists["Discussion Categories"];
    SPList discussion = myweb.Lists["Team Discussion"];

    System.Text.StringBuilder sp = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    //System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

    sp.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
    sp.Append("<tags>");

    foreach (SPListItem category in categories.Items)
    {            
        string categoryname = category.Name;
        categoryname = categoryname.Replace(" ", "%20");
        sp.Append("<a href='" + myweb.Url + "/Pages/Home.aspx?Discussion=" + categoryname + "' style='font-size: 13.5pt'  color='0x7b7b7b'>" + category.Name + "</a>");
    }
    sp.Append("</tags>");

    myweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    return sp.ToString();

}
```

but in the output it shows as : tag opening and closing of the tags node in &lt and &gt . how to correct this?

Comment: sp.Append(<tags>"); is there in the above code. it doesn't showing in the above code

Comment: What are you category names like? Are they valid XML? What is `sp` and how is it declared?

Comment: category names are valid. sp is a stringbuilder object. and in the pageload i wrote response.write(sp);response.end();

Comment: before starting of the <tags>, shall i add <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> to that stringbuilder object, so that it may work?

Comment: How are you outputting this? Can you post the code?

Comment: i edited my post. please check

Comment: @Oded actually i found the error. one of the category name is having like a & b, the special character  & is casuing the error. so how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue is with a `&` in one of the category names, all you need to do is escape it - there are five characters that need to be escaped in XML:

- & -  `&amp;`
- < -  `&lt;`
- > - `&gt;`
- " -  `&quot;`
- ' -  `&apos;`

In the case of `&`, simply replace it with `&amp;`.

Having said that, if you are writing XML you should be using an `XmlWriter` and not a `StringBuilder` - this will escape the characters correctly and this kind of error will not occur:

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out);
writer.WriteStartElement("Foo");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Bar", "Some & value");
writer.WriteElementString("Nested", "data & data");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-code).