# How to write xml file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am newer person in c# asp.net .
I want to write xml file in c# code behind file in my asp.net web application and pass this xml file as a string to a webservice . Can any one able to help me its will very useful for my project .
Thank you

Comment: The question is not clear, please elaborate a little more... what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As "fiver" had mentioned you could use the XmlDocument or the new simplified version XDocument for creating XML Documents. Here's a sample code snippet from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx) for creating XML documents and writing to a file.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
        new XElement("Child", "content")
    )
);
doc.Save("Root.xml");
```

This will write the following text to the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Child>content</Child>
</Root>
```

Note: XDocument is supported only on .NET framework 3.5 and above

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize objects in Xml by using `XmlSerializer` class:

**Serializing to a file:**

```
    void SaveAsXmlToFile(object o, string fname)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
        using (var f = File.Open(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            ser.Serialize(f, o);
    }
```

You can also use `DataContractSerializer` class the same way as `XmlSerializer`.

You can also serialize an object to a string, and return it:

**Serializing to a string:**

```
    string ToXml(object o)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            ser.Serialize(sw, o);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Also, if you need more control over produced Xml, you can use structured xml objects, like `XmlDocument` and so on, or xml writing classes like `XmlWriter` as denoted in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class. It has various `CreateXXX` methods for creating XML elements.

It seem you don't need to save the XML file, so you can use the `Save(String)` method to serialize it to a string, when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

See this question:
[How can I build XML in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-code)

If you're using .Net4 the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class would work, for .Net2 use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

The [XDocument.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) directly returns the XML as a string. For the XmlDocument class you would use the XmlDocument.Save() method, to save to a stream or a TextWriter [XmlDocument.OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) property.

Both examples on that question demonstrate how to output it as a string. You can use that to pass the string to your web service.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

XmlTextWriter xtwFeed = new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("rss.xml"), Encoding.UTF8);

        xtwFeed.WriteStartDocument();

        // The mandatory rss tag

        xtwFeed.WriteStartElement("rss");

        xtwFeed.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0");

        // Write all the tags like above and end all elements

        xtwFeed.WriteEndElement();
        xtwFeed.WriteEndDocument();
        xtwFeed.Flush();
        xtwFeed.Close();
```

Comment: You can create a StringWriter and pass it to the XmlTextWriter constructor and call ToString on it to get the results as a string too.