# System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'AMP'. Line 88, position 68

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting the follow error, but not sure how to resolve it:

> System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'AMP'.
>   Line 88, position 68.

I found this section in the xml:

```
<AddressData city="TYNE &AMP; WEAR">
    <addressLine>123 Orange Rd.</addressLine>
    <addressLine></addressLine>
</AddressData>
```

The xml is actually being created dynamically, but when I stepped through it, I noticed that it is coming back as Tyne & Wear, but it is being uppercased  which I have no idea why.  There is a utility routing called XmlEncode that does the following, but not sure it would cover the above scenario.

```
s.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("""", "&quot;")
```

Comment: can you post some of the xml you are trying to parse?

Comment: Do you have an `&AMP;` where there should be an `&amp;`?

Comment: Could we see the relevant code and/or data which is causing the Exception?

Comment: Show your XML which seems to be invalid, or if the file is too large show what you have on line 88.

Comment: @Steven and Mike - I am getting the xml.  I will post it when I get a chance.

Comment: @Anders, Is it invalid to use &AMP; but not &amp;

Comment: XaiSoft: Yes, unless you have declared the entity "AMP". By default, XML only has five entities: `amp`, `quot`, `apos`, `lt`, `gt`.

Comment: Looks like the program is trying to build an XML document by concatenating strings, and this is exactly the kind of bugs you'll run into. Build it using a DOM instead, check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-code

Comment: It looks like the entire `city` attribute is being uppercased somewhere; that's probably what's doing it.

Comment: @Anders, yes that is exactly the way it is doing it.  It is doing it with string builder, but I can't change it now.  How can I change the XmlEncode to return &amp instead of &AMP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the xml input contains an upper-cased `&amp;`. XML character entities are case-sensitive.

Comment: I am trying to get the xml.  I actually don't have it, but as soon as I get it, I will let you know. Thank you so far.