# how to remove xml list name

Tags: xml, serialization

I'm serializing a class that has a list of subclasses. How can I exclude the collection nodes from the xml?  An example will illustruat my point.

```
public class A
{
   public List<Person> People;
}

public class Person
{
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string name;
}
```

This serializes as:

```
<A>
   <People>
     <Person name = "a"/>;
     <Person name = "b"/>;
     <Person name = "c"/>;
   </People>
</A>
```

Now this seems logically correct,  however the xml I am trying to replicate looks like this:

```
<A>
     <Person name = "a"/>;
     <Person name = "b"/>;
     <Person name = "c"/>;
</A>
```

How can this be achieved?

Many thanks

Comment: Jason, is there a reason you can't use the default XML serialization? You generally want common elements grouped under a root element to make it easy to parse and also to serialize back and forth. There is probably a way to reach the result you want via serialization, or you could just write out the XML string or create the XML using the XMLSerializer, XDocument, and XmlWriter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-sharp-code

Comment: Hi Matt, the XML is to be send as a parameter to a webservice and will fail XSD validation if its not exactly like their examples. Its a pretty complex set of classes and I was hoping to avoid building up the XML manually.  Is there not some kind of attribute available to me that lets me control the output?

Comment: If all else fails I think I will just replace the nodes I dont want with an empty string before passing the xml string through to the webservice - bit of a hack - but thats how I roll :)