# String List in C# and XML

Tags: c#, xml

Guys i need to hard Code my XML string list data and then display it as the below out put in a console window!

```
<Photos>
    <Photo> p1.jpg </Photo>
        <Photo> p2.jpg </Photo>
    <Photo> p3.jpg </Photo>
    <Photo> p4.jpg </Photo>
    <Photo> p5.jpg </Photo>
</Photos>
```

This what i have done so far!

```
namespace ConsoleApplication17
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("p1.jpg");
            list.Add("p2.jpg");
            list.Add("p3.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What you have done does not appear to be XML related at all... what exactly are you having trouble with? WHich part?

Comment: You can use a StringBuilder or if you can do a nice XMLSerialization if you take the time to search for that (it's very useful to learn). Or if it's hardcoded, as you say, just make it a big const string.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i need to add data to this string list and display it as above! Please dont down Rate the question, i want be able to ask questions in future!

Comment: I guess the OP wants to generate XML from the string list. You can take a look at how to [construct XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-sharp-code) on the fly first.

Comment: `List<string> list = new List<string>();
  list.Add("p1.jpg");
  list.Add("p2.jpg");
  list.Add("p3.jpg");
var xElement = new XElement ("Photos");
foreach (var item in list)
{
  xElement.Add(new XElement ("Photo", item));
}

Console.WriteLine(xElement);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert your `xml` to a `List<string>()`?

In that case, using `LINQ to XML`:

```
var str = @"<Photos>
    <Photo> p1.jpg </Photo>
    <Photo> p2.jpg </Photo>
    <Photo> p3.jpg </Photo>
    <Photo> p4.jpg </Photo>
    <Photo> p5.jpg </Photo>
    </Photos>";

XDocument.Parse(str)
    .Descendants("Photo")
    .Select (s => s.Value)
    .ToList<string>();
```

---

**Alternatively**, If you want to create XML:

```
var xPhotos = new XElement("Photos");
for (var x = 1; x < 6; x++) {
    xPhotos.Add(new XElement("Photo", "p" + x + ".jpg"));
}
var xdoc = new XDocument(xPhotos);
```

The above assumes you have a set limit of numbers for your jpg names.

---

**OR**, if you want to create xml from the `List<string>()` that you already have:

```
// your existing code:
List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("p1.jpg");
            list.Add("p2.jpg");
            list.Add("p3.jpg");

// to xml:
var xPhotos = new XElement("Photos");
foreach(string x in list)
    xPhotos.Add(new XElement("Photo", x));
var xdoc = new XDocument(xPhotos);
```