# How do I generate and write XML file of this format?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm sorry, I'm not good with XML APIs. How would I generate an XML file of the following format and write it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<ROOT>
  <LOC ID="*">
    <ROW ID = "1" CD = "US" DESC = "United States" ISACTIVE="1" ORDER="1"/>
    <ROW ID = "2" CD = "CA" DESC = "Canada" ISACTIVE="1" ORDER="2"/>
    <ROW ID = "3" CD = "XX" DESC = "Others" ISACTIVE="1" ORDER="3"/>
  </LOC>
</ROOT>
```

Here's my best first attempt. The hardcoded values would have to be replaced by values from the database. I don't know how to iterate and create the multiple row elements.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ROOT");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

XmlNode locNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LOC");
XmlAttribute attr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("ID");
attr.Value = "*";
rootNode.AppendChild(locNode);

XmlNode rowNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ROW");
XmlAttribute id = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("CD");
id.Value = "1";
XmlAttribute cd = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("CD");
cd.Value = "US";
XmlAttribute desc = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("DESC");
desc.Value = "United States";
XmlAttribute active = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("ISACTIVE");
active.Value = "1";
XmlAttribute order = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("ORDER");
order.Value = "1";
rootNode.AppendChild(rowNode);

xmlDoc.Save("foo.xml");
```

Comment: Let's see how far you have gotten so far?

Comment: Post your best attempt and let us know what the problems are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to build XML in C# code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-xml-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: There's an enormous amount of documentation and examples around building/reading XML if you'd just bother to look for it. Go do some research and try it yourself and come back when you run into a problem with *code you've written*. Without any actual effort shown, it sounds like you're just asking us to do it for you.

Comment: I understand and I am coding my best attempt as we speak.

Comment: I've updated the above to show my best attempt.

Comment: You would "iterate and create" the multi row elements by using a loop. If it's coming from a database, it would probably need to be a `while` that would terminate when you reach the end of the data. If it's a finite number, a `for` loop would work. There's nothing complicated about the loop itself. For each element you need to add, you create the element, add the attributes and set values just as you are and append them to `locNode` (not the `rootNode`).

Comment: How about the XML? Is it anywhere close? I don't know the APIs but I made my best attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier `using System.Xml.Linq`;

```
    ...
    var xml = new XElement("ROOT", 
        new XElement("LOC", new XAttribute("ID", "*"),
            CreateRow(1, "US", "United States", 1, 1),
            CreateRow(2, "CA", "Canada", 1, 2),
            CreateRow(3, "XX", "UOthers", 1, 3)));

    Console.WriteLine(xml);
}

static XElement CreateRow(int id, string cd, string desc, int isActive, int order)
{
    return new XElement("ROW",
        new XAttribute("ID", id),
        new XAttribute("CD", cd),
        new XAttribute("DESC", desc),
        new XAttribute("ISACTIVE", isActive),
        new XAttribute("ORDER", order));
}
```

Loop;

```
var xml = new XElement("LOC", new XAttribute("ID", "*"));

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    xml.Add(CreateRow(i, "?", "?", 1, i));
}

Console.WriteLine(new XElement("ROOT", xml));
```

Comment: The only thing is how do I put a forach loop in this code to call CreateRow the correct number of times?

Comment: Only thing - I am not in  a console app. How would I/what would I set it to the line new XElement("ROOT", xml);

Comment: `xml = new XElement("ROOT", xml);`