# Converting specific HTML structure to specific XML structure

Tags: c#, html, xml, recursion, html-agility-pack

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now.

I want to convert the html to xml. The structures is shown below.

I am using "HtmlAgilityPack" to convert the html to valid xml structure. So, after this, my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="menuItem1" video="" preview="">
    Menu 1
    <div class="subMenu1">
        <div class="menuItem2" video="" preview="">
            Menu 2
            <div class="subMenu2">
                <div class="menuItem3" video="" preview="">
                    Menu 3
                    <div class="subMenu3">
                        <div class="" video="" preview="">Menu 4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="treeExpand"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="" preview="">Menu 3</div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="" preview="">Menu 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="treeExpand"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="treeExpand"></div>
</div>
<div class="menuItem1" video="" preview="">
    Menu 1
    <div class="subMenu1">
        <div class="menuItem2" video="" preview="">
            Menu 2
            <div class="subMenu2">
                <div class="menuItem3" video="" preview="">
                    Menu 3
                    <div class="subMenu3">
                        <div class="" video="" preview="">Menu 4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="treeExpand"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="" preview="">Menu 3</div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="" preview="">Menu 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="treeExpand"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="treeExpand"></div>
</div>
```

Which is exactly what I want. Now I can get this into an XElement, using this C# code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(THE_HTML_STRING_AS_SHOWN_ABOVE);
XDocument docw = new XDocument(new XElement("Navigation", doc.Root));
XElement root = docw.Root;
```

I created a method, which I can pass the root into:

```
GenerateXmlFromHtml(root);
```

The code for this method:

```
private string GenerateXmlFromHtml(XElement elem)
{
    StringBuilder sbNavigationXml = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        //HTML will always have a video and preview, according to the generation of the html structure.

        string text = string.Empty;
        string videopath = string.Empty;
        string previewpath = string.Empty;
        XText textNode;

        foreach (XElement element in elem.Elements())
        {
            element.Name = "MenuItem"; //Change element name.

            string htmlClass;
            try { htmlClass = element.Attribute("class").Value; }
            catch { htmlClass = ""; }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlClass))
            {
                if (htmlClass.Contains("subMenu"))
                {
                    element.AddBeforeSelf(element.Elements());
                    element.Remove();
                    GenerateXmlFromHtml(element);
                }
                else if (htmlClass.Contains("menuItem"))
                {
                    textNode = element.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault();
                    text = textNode.Value;
                    videopath = element.Attribute("video").Value;
                    previewpath = element.Attribute("preview").Value;

                    if (element.HasElements)
                    {
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine("<MenuItem Text=\"" + text + "\" VideoPath=\"" + videopath + "\" PreviewPath=\"" + previewpath + "\">");
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine(GenerateXmlFromHtml(element));
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine("</MenuItem>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine("<MenuItem Text=\"" + text + "\" VideoPath=\"" + videopath + "\" PreviewPath=\"" + previewpath + "\" />");
                    }
                }
                else if (htmlClass.Contains("treeExpand"))
                {
                    element.AddBeforeSelf(element.Elements());
                    element.Remove();
                    GenerateXmlFromHtml(element);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                element.AddBeforeSelf(element.Elements());
                element.Remove();
                GenerateXmlFromHtml(element);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return sbNavigationXml.ToString();
}
```

At the end, I want this to produce this XML output:

```
<Navigation>
  <MenuItem Text="Menu 1" VideoPath="" PreviewPath="">
    <MenuItem Text="Menu 2">
      <MenuItem Text="Menu 3">
        <MenuItem Text="Menu 4" VideoPath="" PreviewPath="" />
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem Text="Menu 3" />
      <MenuItem Text="Menu 3" />
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Text="Menu 1" VideoPath="" PreviewPath="">
    <MenuItem Text="Menu 2">
      <MenuItem Text="Menu 3">
        <MenuItem Text="Menu 4" VideoPath="" PreviewPath="" />
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem Text="Menu 3" />
      <MenuItem Text="Menu 3" />
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
</Navigation>
```

In other words, the sub menu's should fall away, as well as the tree expand divs, and I then want to produce the XML, but at the moment, I'm still failing miserably. Please ask if something is not clear. Any help appreciated!!!

===================================================================================================

EDIT:
The fixed recursive method, for anyone who want to see:

```
private string GenerateXmlFromHtml(XElement elem)
{
    //HTML will always have a video and preview, according to the generation of the html structure.
    StringBuilder sbNavigationXml = new StringBuilder();
    string text = string.Empty;
    string videopath = string.Empty;
    string previewpath = string.Empty;
    XText textNode;

    try
    {
        foreach (XElement element in elem.Elements())
        {
            //element.Name = "MenuItem"; //Change element name.
            string htmlClass;
            try { htmlClass = element.Attribute("class").Value; }
            catch { htmlClass = ""; }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlClass))
            {
                if (htmlClass.Contains("subMenu"))
                {
                    if (element.HasElements)
                    {
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine(GenerateXmlFromHtml(element));
                    }
                }
                else if (htmlClass.Contains("menuItem"))
                {
                    textNode = element.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault(); //Get node Text attribute value.
                    text = textNode.Value;
                    videopath = element.Attribute("video").Value; //Get node VideoPath attribute value.
                    previewpath = element.Attribute("preview").Value; //Get node PreviewPath attribute value.

                    if (element.HasElements)
                    {
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine("<MenuItem Text=\"" + text + "\" VideoPath=\"" + videopath + "\" PreviewPath=\"" + previewpath + "\">");
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine(GenerateXmlFromHtml(element));
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine("</MenuItem>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbNavigationXml.AppendLine("<MenuItem Text=\"" + text + "\" VideoPath=\"" + videopath + "\" PreviewPath=\"" + previewpath + "\" />");
                    }
                }
                else if (htmlClass.Contains("treeExpand"))
                {
                    //DO NOTHING
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (element.HasElements)
                {
                    sbNavigationXml.AppendLine(GenerateXmlFromHtml(element));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return sbNavigationXml.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Side note: Usually people get it wrong other way around - parse HTML with Regex, but still construct XML with proper APIs. Is there a reason why you need to use string concatenation to build XML?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - No, I am able to do anything I want... this is just the path I took, but anything else to produce that XML output will be fine, even if I have to do something totally different.

Comment: Check out [How can I build XML in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/how-can-i-build-xml-in-c) for guidance.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - That is all good, but i think I have a problem with my recursive method then. because I don't see all the nodes. seems like only up to the second menu item level.

Comment: Suggestion: You are changing HTML tree while walking it. It makes code almost impossible to comprehend. Try to avoid doing so and it may just fix itself.

Comment: Hmmmm... let me try something with this in mind...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - You are right, that resolved my problem. It really fixed itself after I just added an extra AppendLine if there is no htmlClass. Thanx. If you want you can post it as an answer and I will accept then. Else, THANX for helping me resolve this problem!

Comment: rodrigogq post have good code sample - I think it answers the question enough (showing proper recursion/XML creation). I think it is much better approach that you have and recommend accepting it as an answer (irrespective how you fixed your current issue). Additionally you can write up self-answer showing the fix if you want to with remark like "use XML creation API....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating the input and output on different documents.

Then navigate the input and start outputting this to your XmlDocument output (another variable) in the format you want.

Something like...

```
class Converter
{
    public XmlDocument Convert(XmlDocument inputDocument)
    {
        XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
        ConvertNode(inputDocument.DocumentElement, result.DocumentElement, result);
        return result;
    }

    public void ConvertNode(XmlNode inputNode, XmlNode outputNode, XmlDocument outputDoc)
    {
        XmlNode newNode = null;

        // check elemment class
        string htmlClass;
        try { htmlClass = inputNode.Attributes["class"].Value; }
        catch { htmlClass = ""; }

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(htmlClass))
        {
            if (htmlClass.Contains("menuItem"))
            {
                newNode = outputDoc.CreateElement("MenuItem");
                outputNode.AppendChild(newNode);
            }

            /// check other wanted nodes etc..
        }

        if (newNode != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in inputNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                ConvertNode(node, newNode, outputDoc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a Parser. that is how I get the html into a valid xml structure, then I handle this as normal xml using XElement.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question... Have you even seen code in the post?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I guess the separation still applies. I changed to just the significant part.

Comment: Have you looked at the post at all - your suggestion is exactly what OP is doing... and such suggestion should be comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I can't comment yet. That being so, I only can "answer".

Comment: @FrederikMoller This is the idea I was trying to tell you. It is not final, but I guess can show you the way.

Comment: @rodrigogq - you should have just started with your code and avoid "answer as comment" altogether.

Comment: Well, I see where you want to go... but I cannot accept this answer. I did what Alexei said - should not edit the elements as I navigate. That resolved the problem. - But thanx for the help.

Comment: Accepted as best solution