# How to convert NameValueCollection to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, namevaluecollection

How can I convert a NameValueCollection like:

```
  var mydata = new NameValueCollection();
    mydata.Add("UserID", "3698521478963");
    mydata.Add("Password", "23584");
    mydata.Add("VerifyCode", "23654");
```

to a XML String like this :

XML Data:

[image: XML Data]  ?

Comment: can u provide sample data

Comment: Language? Also, please don't use images of code. That's a filthy habit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build XML in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/how-can-i-build-xml-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ-to-XML to achieve that, for example :

```
var mydata = new NameValueCollection();
mydata.Add("UserID", "3698521478963");
mydata.Add("Password", "23584");
mydata.Add("VerifyCode", "23654");

var result = new XElement("Root",
                            mydata.AllKeys.Select(o => new XElement(o, mydata[o]))
                         );
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8kMzWD1)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<Root>
  <UserID>3698521478963</UserID>
  <Password>23584</Password>
  <VerifyCode>23654</VerifyCode>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Spot on!

Comment: is it possible also to deserialize the XML and rebuild the original NameValueCollection with this approach?