# Create XMl file in particular format in c#

Tags: c#, xml

i want to create xml file in c# in below format.

```html
<custom>
<text1>
<value name="sample1">hello</value>
</text1>
<text1><value name="sample2">world</value> 
</text1>  
</custom>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Carra, I think that's a demand. Write it for him now!

Comment: @NitinK What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build XML in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/how-can-i-build-xml-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication85
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //<custom>
            //    <text1>
            //    <value name="sample1">hello</value>
            //    </text1>
            //    <text1><value name="sample2">world</value> 
            //    </text1>  
            //    </custom>

            XElement custom = new XElement("custom", new object[] {
                new XElement("Text1", new object[] {
                   new XElement("value", new object[] {
                      new XAttribute("name", "sample1"),
                      "hello"
                   })
                }),
                new XElement("Text1", new object[] {
                   new XElement("value", new object[] {
                      new XAttribute("name", "sample2"),
                      "world"
                   })
                })
            });

        }
    }
}
```