# C# writing a single " to a file

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to write a single " to a file in C# as I can't seem to get the escape sequence to work. The idea being I want to write the line survey id="6737AF7F-F422-4995-B781-B3DE315DFE6D" to a file where the GUID itself is user input.

my current code for this is

```
XML.Add("<survey id=" + "\"\"" + surveyGUID.Text + "\"\"" + ">");
```

which writes survey id=""6737AF7F-F422-4995-B781-B3DE315DFE6D"".

Every variation I've tried either won't build, comes out the same way or writes survey id=\"6737AF7F-F422-4995-B781-B3DE315DFE6D\". Can this be done? Is there another escape sequence I don't know about?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you manually writing out your XML? There are plenty of classes for that. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/how-can-i-build-xml-in-c) to make your life easier.

Comment: it was not showing it.. it is now..

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you want:

```
XML.Add("<survey id=" + "\"" + surveyGUID.Text + "\"" + ">");
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect thanks! I'm sure I tried that...

Answer (score 1):

just remove one of your escaped quotes on each side.

```
XML.Add("<survey id=" + "\"" + surveyGUID.Text + "\"" + ">");
```