# .NET CORE generate XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

I'm searching for a good way to generate an XML by a specific format. After checking several guids and SO questions(which I'm to newbie to understand most of them) I've encountered the [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/creating-xml-trees-linq-to-xml-2) feature for buildig a "tree" .

This could work, according to the link, you can nest an `XElement` over and over and create the desired hierarchy. My problem is that I need to load records from my database.

So my question is - Is there a way to create an `XElement` which will be the `ROOT`, and then for each record from my table, create another `XElement` and populate all the necessary details, and then attach it to the original `root`? Or am I going in the wrong direction and there's an easier way around it.

Comment: What database? Quite a few have built-in XML support, saving you the trouble (for example, SQL Server's `FOR XML`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build XML in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/how-can-i-build-xml-in-c)

Comment: You may be interested in the DataTable's WriteXML method.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could just serialise an object too, there are a load of different ways to achieve this, the SQL FOR XML might be the easiest unless you really need to do this inside your library.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a .NET Core specific issue. Why not using the FOR XML PATH clause in your SQL statement to get the XML formatted data like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee 
FOR XML PATH('Employee'), ROOT ('Employees')
```

More information can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-path-mode?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Because I need it in a specific format, with many records grouped by with more than 1 hierarchy level , how can I achieve it with FOR XML PATH?

Comment: This is also possible with FOR XML PATH. Search for the term 'hierarchy' in the above mentioned Microsoft documentation.